# How to count number of columns in a table in SQLITE?

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I count the number of columns in a table in a sqlite database in Android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query) returns a `Cursor` which has methods like [`getColumnCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnCount()).

Comment: You can LIMIT the query to 1 to reduce access time

Answer (score 8):

You can use `pragma table_info(foo_table)` and count the number of rows returned

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code and it runs perfectly without any error.

```
public Cursor getAllTitles(){
   return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
        KEY_ROWID,KEY_ISBN,KEY_TITLE,KEY_PUBLISHER},
        null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Now create the following object in onCreate() method to call above getAllTitles() method.

```
Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
c.getColumnCount(); //this line will give the number of columns in table.
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the parameters of the db.query()? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SELECT count() FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('your_table');`

Reference:
https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragfunc

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
-(NSInteger)dbFieldCount:(NSString *)dbname
{
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PRAGMA table_info(%@)",dbname];
    const char *query2 = [query UTF8String];
    NSInteger nFields =0;
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query2, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
         while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
         {
               nFields++;
         }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    return nFields;
}
```

Comment: This code could not work in java, android and uses objective-c as prog language.

Comment: `sqlite3_data_count` or `sqlite3_column_count` is good alternative to looping.