# Find number of columns in a table | Sqlite3

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, better-sqlite3

I am using cpp and -lsqlite3 to handle some data. I just wanted to ask about a query that will return the number of columns of a specific table in sqlite. Is it possible to find out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301320/how-to-count-number-of-columns-in-a-table-in-sqlite

Comment: [Docs](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) have the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sufficiently recent SQLite version:

```
select count(*)
from pragma_table_info('tableName')
```

---

If it doesn't have to be a SQL query but could be an API call, then a) prepare a query `select * from tableName` (just prepare, you don't need to actually execute it), then call `sqlite3_column_count` on the resulting statement handle.